# Is it possible to type out the Chinese quotation marks "「 」" within a math environment?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, brackets

I wonder if it is possible to type out the Chinese quotation marks "「 」" within a math environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for `\ulcorner` and `\lrcorner`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$\ulcorner x\lrcorner$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks more like `\lceil`, `\rfloor`. I'd probably redefine them as left and right chinese quotes and i'd make a macro;

```
\newcommand{\lchquote}{\lceil}
\newcommand{\rchquote}{\rfloor}
\newcommand{\chquote}[1]{\ensuremath{\left\lchquote\, #1 \,\right\rchquote}}
```

so that, for example it would render as[image: chquotes] for large operators

Comment: Thanks. It is a good alternative. I was after the \ulcorner \lrcorner solution.